# Kill infinite loop plperl

Tags: postgresql, perl, hang, kill

How can I kill session with infinite looped plperl function?

Both `pg_terminate_backend` and `pg_cancel_backend` had no effect. `kill -1 pid` did nothing as well and `kill -9 pid` crashed server.

Comment: yeah `kill -9` on a backend is documented as causing an unclean shutdown closing all sessions and requiring a recovery at restart.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct,

```
CREATE FUNCTION foo()
RETURNS void
AS $$
  while(1) {}
$$ LANGUAGE plperl;

SELECT * FROM foo();
```

Having called `pg_terminate_backend` and `pg_cancel_backend` that plperl backend persists. Seems to be a bug that they already know about, [from the lists  Tom Lane says,](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html)

> Even assuming that we can fix the garden-variety bugs like these, there's still a **fundamental problem that an uncooperative user function
>   (particularly one in plperl/pltcl/plpython) can indefinitely delay
>   response to `pg_terminate_backend`.**  Maybe that's okay, seeing that it can similarly hold off or disregard `QueryCancel`, but I'm not sure the people asking for this are really gonna be satisfied.  (One thing we 
>   should consider is making `ERRCODE_ADMIN_SHUTDOWN` unconditionally untrappable by plpgsql exception blocks, which'd at least fix the issue for plpgsql functions.)

I am not sure they have a solution to this or not. From a Craig Ringer,

> In general it's safe to use `pg_terminate_backend` as a "bigger hammer". `SIGTERM` as sent by  `pg_terminate_backend()` will often, **but not always**, cause a backend that can't respond to a cancel to exit.

He even goes into explaining some of the options that [can cause the hang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41413762/124486).

Anyway, let's try something

```
CREATE FUNCTION foo()
RETURNS void
AS $$
  $SIG{INT} = $SIG{TERM} = sub { die; };
  while(1) {}
$$ LANGUAGE plperl;
```

Then I ran

```
SESSION 1                           SESSION 2

SELECT pg_backend_pid();
 pg_backend_pid 
----------------
          20465

SELECT * FROM foo();
-- LOOPING

                                    pg_terminate_backend(20465);


ERROR:  Died at line 2.
CONTEXT:  PL/Perl function "foo"
```

That seems to work, if it's an option.

Answer (score 0):

I caused an infinite loop with the `DO` statement below on psql:

```sql
DO $$
DECLARE
  num INT := 0;
BEGIN
  LOOP
    RAISE INFO '%', num;
    num := num + 1;
  END LOOP;
END
$$;
```

Then, it took me about a long time to automatically stop(kill) the infinite loop with the error below:

> ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request

But, holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> took me only 6 seconds to manually stop(kill) the infinite loop with the error below:

> ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request

And, I caused an infinite loop with the `DO` statement below on psql:

```sql
DO $$
BEGIN
  LOOP
  END LOOP;
END
$$;
```

Then, as soon as I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, I could manually stop(kill) the infinite loop with the error below:

> ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request